# Integration problem and Hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int \frac{e^{(b-r)x}}{a+e^{bx}}$$

Using integral by parts I was able to derive the following result:
$$\int \frac{e^{(b-r)x}}{a+e^{bx}} = \frac{ 1}{(b-r)}\cdot \frac {e^{(b-r)x}}{(a+e^{bx})}+\frac{ b }{(b-r)(2b-r)}\cdot \frac{e^{(2b-r)x}}{(a+e^{bx})^2}+\frac{ 2b^2 }{(b-r)(2b-r)(3b-r)}\cdot \frac{e^{(3b-r)x}}{(a+e^{bx})^3} + . . . . . .. . . . . . . . . .   $$

When I used Wolfram Alpha to evaluate the same integral result is different:
$$\int \frac{e^{(b-r)x}}{a+e^{bx}} = \frac{e^{(b-r)x}}{a(b-r)} \cdot {}_2F_1(1, 1-\frac1R,2-\frac2R,\frac{-e^{bz}}{a})$$
$$ = \frac{ 1}{(b-r)}\cdot \frac {e^{(b-r)x}}{a}+\frac{ 1 }{(2b-r)}\cdot \frac{e^{(2b-r)x}}{a^2}+\frac{ 1 }{(3b-r)}\cdot \frac{e^{(3b-r)x}}{a^3} + . . . . . .. . . . . . . . . .   $$

Can you tell me which of the two results is correct? Or both are correct? How can I rearrange my result to get the Wolfram Alpha result (assuming both are equal and correct)?

In addition to above, the series obtained by Wolfram is convergent and the series that I got from integral by parts is divergent. Please help. Which solution should I use? Is it possible to convert my solution from being divergent to convergent? (I used ratio test to check convergence/divergence)

Comment: you can differentiate both Solutions to see what result is correct

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I just verified the result I got with differentiation, however, I can't verify the result obtained form Wolfram. What could be the issue with Wolfram's result?